Trouble with Discord.py
I've been trying to make a Discord bot that will listen for a $start command from a guild and then starts an Exaroton Minecraft server using their API. I've been using some templates to get it to only respond to what I say yet it is still not working. The platform I am using to do this is Replit.
import os
import random  # Import the 'random' module

import discord
from discord import Intents
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"Message received: {message.content}")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    brooklyn_99_quotes = [
        'I\'m the human form of the  emoji.',
        'Bingpot!',
        (
            'Cool. Cool cool cool cool cool cool cool, '
            'no doubt no doubt no doubt no doubt.'
        ),
    ]

    if '99!' in message.content:
        response = random.choice(brooklyn_99_quotes)
        await message.channel.send(response)

async def start_bot():
    await client.start(TOKEN)

async def main():  
    await start_bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    discord.Client.run(client, TOKEN)  # Run the client with the provided token


Check if your: Intents are enabled in the app portal for discord (this ensures that we don't have any problems there), you're actually getting the messages in the first place (have a print statement for message content in the actual event), and other debugging information that could be useful

Thank you for the idea, somehow it is now working (however I don't know why). The only issue is that it can only ready DMs but not Guild Messages. I gave it access to message content intent on the app portal, however it still can not see it. In the Console it knows that there is a message and from my username, however it does not print the message content nor respond

You have to reinvite your bot to the server

You need to enable the message_content intent, not messages.
Also, the guilds intent is already enabled in default Intents, so you do not need to manually enable it.
intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

